# C# Uploading a memorystream object to Web API

Tags: c#, csv, upload, webclient

I have an CSV file in memory that I want to upload to a Web API.

If I save the CSV file to disk and upload it, it gets accepted.

However, I want to avoid the extra work and also make the code cleaner by simply uploading the text I have as a MemoryStream Object (I think that's the correct format?).

The following code works for uploading the file:

```
string webServiceUrl = "XXX";
string filePath = @"C:\test.csv";
string cred = "YYY";

using (var client = new WebClient()){
    client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + cred);
    byte[] rawResponse = client.UploadFile(webServiceUrl, "POST", filePath);   
    Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rawResponse));
}
```

How would I do if I had a string with all the contents and I want to upload it in the same way without having to save it down to a file?

WebClient.UploadData or WebClient.UploadString perhaps?

Thank you

EDIT:

I tried what you said but by using a local file (in case there was something wrong with the string), but I get the same error.

Here is what I suppose the code would be using your solution

```
string webServiceUrl = "XXX";
string file = @"C:\test.csv";     
string cred = "YYY";

FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(fs);
byte[] postArray = r.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length); 

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + cred);
    using (var postStream = client.OpenWrite(webServiceUrl, "POST"))
    {     
          postStream.Write(postArray, 0, postArray.Length); 
    }              
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use one of the WebClient UploadData overrides. Pass in the MemoryStream's ToArray as the byte[] parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it.

First I made a request using CURL that worked.
I analyzed the packet data and made an except copy of the packet.

I did a lot of changes, however, the final change was that using the different functions I found online it never closed the packet with a "Last-Boundary" while CURL did.

So by modifying the function, making sure it properly wrote a Last-Boundary it finally worked.

Also, another crucial thing was to set PreAuthenticate to true, the examples online didn't do that.

So, all in all:
1. Make sure that the packet is properly constructed.
2. Make sure you pre authenticate if you need to authenticate.

```
webrequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
webrequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", cred);
```

3. Don't forget to add SSL if using a https (which you probably do if you authenticate):

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

Hope this helps someone.

And thanks for the help earlier!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`OpenWrite()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t27yce3(v=vs.110).aspx) from the WebClient.

```
using (var postStream = client.OpenWrite(endpointUrl))
{
    postStream.Write(memStreamContent, 0, memStream.Length);
}
```

As documentation mentioned:

> The OpenWrite method returns a writable stream that is used to send data to a resource.

---

### Update

Try to set the position of the MemoryStream to 0 before uploading.

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

When you copy the file into the MemoryStream, the pointer is moved to the end of the stream, so when you then try to read it, you're **getting a null byte** instead of your stream data.

#### MSDN - [CopyTo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Copying begins at the current position in the current stream, and does not reset the position of the destination stream after the copy operation is complete.

Comment: Which Error did you get?

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
It's not more specific than that.

Comment: @Roffemon Can you debug the Server? This error message means the Server can't handle Stream's as Input.

Comment: Can't, it's a server that I don't have access to. The second code block is very similar to the first, so I must be doing something wrong when handling the stream?

I'll try and see if I can solve it, thank you!

Comment: @Roffemon Check the position of your MemStream in the debugger before posting to the Server.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. Same error message.

Comment: I tried an example that seems to be working and added my credentials, same error, https://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/942278-how-upload-file-via-c-code.

I'll just save it down to a file for now and get back to it if I have spare time. Perhaps a server issue.

Thanks for spending time on this.